# how to store duration in a pandas column in minutes:second format that allows arithemtic?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am storing duration in a pandas column using strings.
For example '12:05' stands for 12 minutes and 5 seconds.

I would like to convert this pandas column from string to a format that allows arithmetic, while retaining the MM:SS format.

I would like to avoid storing day, hour, dates, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

real `Timedelta` support is available in 0.15.0, see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to convert to date time but still want to do math with them you'd most like be best off converting them to seconds in a different column while retaining the string format of them or creating a function that converts to string and applying that after any computations.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably store the time as seconds, e.g. `12*60 + 5 = 725` for `'12:05'`.
When printing you can use the [to_string](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) function to give that column a formatter that prints it in 'MM:SS' format. That formatter is pretty trivial to write yourself.